# Why is a code coverage report published as an Artifact when I have publishJUnitResults set to false?

Tags: maven, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

The reason I want to disable it is that it adds about an extra 30 seconds to my pipeline when I don't even need it. All I want is for the report to be published to Sonarqube, which is working fine.

My pipeline YAML file:

```yaml
trigger: none
pool:
  name: <REDACTED>
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>
  
stages:
- stage: InstallJava
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
            script: |
              echo Write your commands here
              echo Hello world
              pwd
              dir
              mvn -version
              java -version
              mvn clean compile
              export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.21.0.9-1.el7_9.x86_64'
      - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          artifactsFeeds: '<REDACTED>'
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
        inputs:
          SonarQube: '<REDACTED> SonarQube'
          scannerMode: 'Other'
      - task: Maven@4
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
          goals: 'clean install'
          publishJUnitResults: false
          javaHomeOption: 'path'
          codeCoverageToolOption: 'JaCoCo'
          jdkDirectory: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk'
          mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
          mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
          effectivePomSkip: false
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
      - task: SonarQubePublish@5
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

The code coverage report being generated as an Artifact:
[image: Code coverage report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question *WHY*, this unfortunately appears to be by design. The Maven task has the following logic, lifted from the source code of the [Maven@4 task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/511930abe4df849ecbdead1389acb9baade92480/Tasks/MavenV4/maventask.ts#L133C1-L142C1).

```java
 // Maven task orchestration occurs as follows:
 // 1. Check that Maven exists by executing it to retrieve its version.
 // 2. Apply any goals for static code analysis tools selected by the user.
 // 3. Run Maven. Compilation or test errors will cause this to fail.
 //    In case the build has failed, the analysis will still succeed but the report will have less data. 
 // 4. Attempt to collate and upload static code analysis build summaries and artifacts.
 // 5. Always publish test results even if tests fail, causing this task to fail.
 // 6. If #3 or #4 above failed, exit with an error code to mark the entire step as failed.
```

Step #5 has some logic to fail the build if the coverage is empty, which appears to be coupled with the [implementation of publishing code-coverage artifacts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/511930abe4df849ecbdead1389acb9baade92480/Tasks/MavenV4/maventask.ts#L299C1-L314C15).

[image: Publish code coverage results]

I'm assuming that you want both code coverage and unit-test results to be included in the data set published to SonarQube. If they are not needed at all, you can prevent publishing by setting the `codeCoverageToolOption` to `none`, which will set the `isCodeCoverageOpted` variable (shown above) to false.

Comment: You could always log a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks -- might be as simple as `isCodeCoverageOpted && publishJUnitResults`